# How to use spinner and fill it from array in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm a newbie in Android Development and I want to implement `Spinner`. My problem is that I have an array which has 9 values for a key Category. My array looks like:

```
MyArray
[{Category=Things To Do}, 
 {Category=Transportation}, 
 {Category=Food  and  Drink}, 
 {Category=Accommodation}, 
 {Category=Shopping},
 {Category=Money and Costs}, 
 {Category=Business}, 
 {Category=Turkey Tour},
 {Category=Events}]
```

I want to get value of category key. i need MyArray for spinner as bellow:

```
MyArray
    {
    Things To Do
    Transportation
    Food and Drink
    Accommodation
    Shopping
    ......    
    }
```

It is similar to iPhone code.

```
// iPhone code 
for(int i=0; i<[arrayCategory count]; i++)
    {
    NSString *strSubTitle=[[arrayCategory objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"category"];
    }
```

Any idea?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have to parse wizardistanbul.net/wizardistanbul/mobilewebservices/… and need to show the category id and category name in spinner.

Comment: MyArray
[{Category=Things To Do}, 
 {Category=Transportation}, 
 {Category=Food  and  Drink}, 
 {Category=Accommodation}, 
 {Category=Shopping},
 {Category=Money and Costs}, 
 {Category=Business}, 
 {Category=Turkey Tour},
 {Category=Events}]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

first create a xml in string for your String array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <string name="planet_prompt">Choose a planet</string>
   <string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
   </string-array>
</resources>
```

then use the above xml for string array in your code like below

```
   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have to parse http://wizardistanbul.net/wizardistanbul/mobilewebservices/iphonerequest_instanbul.php?request=Category and need to show the category id and category name in spinner.

Comment: MyArray after parsing is MyArray [{Category=Things To Do}, {Category=Transportation}, {Category=Food and Drink}, {Category=Accommodation}, {Category=Shopping}, {Category=Money and Costs}, {Category=Business}, {Category=Turkey Tour}, {Category=Events}]

Comment: Nikhil Lamba, thanks for a useful reply. Thhere is some question: why `CharSequence` is used as type for apadper, whereas `String` is expected (by `string-array` resource)? I try `<String>` for adapter in my app, but type mismatch error appears.

Answer (score 5):

try this way, it will work fine.

```
public class ArrayAdapterDemo2 extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView selection;
    String[] category= { "football","cricket" ,"baseball"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category);

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        selection.setText(items[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        selection.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have to parse wizardistanbul.net/wizardistanbul/mobilewebservices/… and need to show the category id and category name in spinner.

Comment: parse data and store in Adapter, and that adapter use for fill data into spinner ok.

Answer (score 0):

If i Understand your question correctly this will be sol
1. Create Spinner Spinner spinner;

2.Create Data `String[] category={"Cricket","football".....};`

3.spinner.setAdapter(new Arrayadapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,category));

4.on selecting particular value on spinner to get the value

```
spinner.setOnItemSelected(new onItemselected(public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
// to get selected Value
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"selected:"+category[pos],5000).show();
});
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fill values in Data String[] category={"Cricket","football".....}... you are telling on static point. Make this string dynamically from parsing array and the developer has parsing array as named MyArray...

Comment: If that is dynamic array use  1.ArrayList<String> 2.make the Length of ArrayList dynamic 3.Use add(index,value) on ArrayList to set the content and finally use that arraylist instead of category array in setAdapter() of spinner

Comment: MyArray after parsing is MyArray
[{Category=Things To Do}, 
 {Category=Transportation}, 
 {Category=Food  and  Drink}, 
 {Category=Accommodation}, 
 {Category=Shopping},
 {Category=Money and Costs}, 
 {Category=Business}, 
 {Category=Turkey Tour},
 {Category=Events}]

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
 Spinner spinnergame;
 String[] games = { "football","cricket" ,"baseball"};

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
 setContentView(R.layout.creategame);

spinnergame = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.game);
spinnergame.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, games);

    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnercity.setAdapter(aa);
public String getSpinnerSelection() {
    return this.selectedspinnervalue;
}

public void setSpinnerSelection(String selection) {
    this.selectedspinnervalue = selection;
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {



}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selection.setText("");

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i think the problem developer is facing is to remove the category tag with = symbol. If you have idea please tell him how to find only array elements dynamically not in the format the asker asked.